# Allocating vs. reusing in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, memory, pool

As a thumb rule, what's better?

1. Allocating a new instances (in my case of UIViewController) when I need them and deallocating ("releasing" my retain of them and therefore allowing them to be deallocated by ARC) when I'm finished, or;
2. Maintaining a dynamic pool of reusable instances and therefore keeping them in memory even when they're not used.

The way I see it, allocating new instances can be hard work but avoids bug due to unexpected state of reused instances, and the burden in the memory of more instances than actually needed at a specific time.

Would love to hear your thoughts about it...

Comment: You dont need to deallocate instances, ARC does it for you.  Do you want your project ARC based or non-ARC ?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear - when I say "deallocating" I mean "releasing" (again, not literally) my retain of the instance (and so allowing it to be deallocated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Premature optimization is a waste of time.   Until you have quantified a performance issue, there is no optimization to be done beyond keeping your code sensible and using reasonable algorithms.

In this case, it is quite likely that allocating anew each time is not going to be an actionable source of performance bottleneck.  However, tasks performed during allocation may be.  For example, creating images or loading resources instead of using a cache of some kind.

But such a bottleneck would be better addressed through caching said resources and not the relatively macro object that is a view controller.

Comment: Makes sense. What would your answer be if we were talking about many instances? do you care more about allocating a (macro) object or 'dragging' it in the memory?

Comment: Ideally, the allocation of a "macro" object -- a control layer object that has hooks into many different parts of the backend and front end-- should be relatively cheap.  It shouldn't be maintaining or calculating a bunch of state, but more reflecting state from the model layer for consumption by the view layer and providing a conduit for reflecting user interaction into changes to model state.   To that end, I generally ignore the issue unless a controller proves expensive to re-allocate. Most often, refactoring the controller provides more universal performance gains...